# Copy/paste local images not working in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, posts, images, pages

This is somehow frustrating. I am ussing the latest version of Wordpress

I am running my webpage, and when I need to copy-paste an image from Internet into any of my posts/pages I have no problem.

However, when I copy/paste any image from my local computer, it is not pasted. Important is that text stored in my computer is copied and pasted without problems. This is what I see regarding images:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Hi, Do you have any specific plugins installed? Because with me, local images (.jpg, .png) work perfectly by copy/paste except if they exceed the authorized size.

Comment: Yes, I use OnePress Image Elevator

Comment: You don't need this plugin to copy/paste a local image. Moreover this plugin has not been updated for 3 years...

Comment: what does it say in english? Does this happen with the onepress image elevator plugin disabled? Is this a programming/development question or a WP user support question?

Comment: I disabled the plugin and same situation. In English it says "upload an image file, choose from the media library or add from URL". So I guess that not from the clipboard to copy/paste